# How to uncheck a checkbox if there are checked more than 3 checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, alert

I have this form:

```
<form name ='vote' action='' method='POST'>
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       <input type='checkbox' name='things[]' value='".$row['name_song']."'
              name='send' onClick='anyCheck(this.form)'>
    } 
    <input type='submit' value='test' name='send'></form>
```

What must I do to make it so that the max times (**t**) that people could vote would be an integer? I wish to pass the value to the anyCheck function as, for example, $maxvotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function anyCheck(f, e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      var t = 0;
      var c = f['things[]'];
      for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
         c[i].checked ? t++ : null;
      }
      if (t == 3) {
         alert("Daugiausiai galite balsuoti už triks kūrinius")
         var targ = event.target || event.srcElement;
         targ.checked = false;
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: jquery: `$('things[]:checked').length > 3 { alert("too many");}`

Comment: Please post what you've tried and the rendered HTML. The PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thats good idea, but that only allerts, but not uncheckes already checked one and if i check 1 more alert is gone..

Comment: @user1883184: so take the hint and do some of the work yourself. that should be enough to get you started. we're not here to do your job for you, just help you through a sticky spot.

Comment: `... .prop('checked', false)`

Comment: i know how to make to add alert, only thing i need is that when getting alert, the checked checkbox would uncheck..

Comment: So, any ideas how should I make it?

Answer (score 1):

Since `anyCheck` is invoked from an event handler, pass the `event` object to the `anyCheck()` function, get the target of the event, and set its `.checked` property to `false`.

```
<input ...  onClick='anyCheck(this.form, event)'>
```

---

```
function anyCheck(f, e) {

    var t = 0;
    var c = f['things[]'];
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        c[i].checked ? t++ : null;
    }
    if (t == 3) {
        alert("You can choose a maximum of 2" + name + "haha");

        (event.target || event.srcElement).checked = false;
    }
}
```

---

Or since the handler is bound directly, you can pass `this` instead.

```
<input ...  onClick='anyCheck(this)'>
```

---

```
function anyCheck(box) {

    var t = 0;
    var c = box.form['things[]'];
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        c[i].checked ? t++ : null;
    }
    if (t == 3) {
        alert("You can choose a maximum of 2" + name + "haha");

        box.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1883184: I updated again to include one more solution. I hadn't noticed that the handler was directly on the checkbox. It's a little simpler with my update.

Comment: Thank you, but one more question, what if t is not 3, but variable i give at onClick?

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires jQuery, although you could rework it to not need the jQuery selectors:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function(e) {
    var num_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if (num_checked > 3) {
      alert("sorry, you have already selected 3 checkboxes!");        
      $(e.target).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
</script>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

As a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RF5Ls/

Comment: Do not use `attr` to set the `checked` *property*!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using attr until they deprecate it, but I updated the code to reflect best practices (at least according to http://api.jquery.com/prop/ )

Comment: The use of `attr` for properties is already deprecated in the recent versions, where it only accesses attributes.

Comment: Do you have a link to support that? https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/unit/attributes.js#L256 appears to refute your claim.

Comment: Not really - jQuery disappoints me one more time. I hope they fix that in 2.0

Comment: @Bergi update: the upgrade docs for 1.9 clarify much better when to use `attr` and when to use `prop`, and verify your claim that using `attr` to set a property has been deprecated since 1.6 (deprecated in word at least, since it doesn't give any errors or warnings): http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-